# Optimización en procedimiento de SQL Server con 120.000 registros

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Tengo un procedimiento en el que debo recorrer una tabla de 120 mil registros e ir realizando cálculos en base a cada registro, el cual contiene un saldo y una fecha de movimiento. El resultado de estos cálculos tengo que guardarlos además en un nuevo registro, ya sea insertándolos en una nueva tabla o añadiendo campos extras a la misma para actualizarlos alli. Elegí el último. El tema es que no hallo la forma de recorrerlos sin un `CURSOR` o un `WHILE`, y con este último el procedimiento tarda más de 10 horas en completarse.

¿Existe otra forma o método de hacerlo?

```
Declare cRetiros INSENSITIVE  Cursor for 
Select tipoMov, fMov,fCierre,vMonto from #temp_ene
FOR READ ONLY

Open cRetiros 
   Fetch Next From cRetiros Into @tipo_mov, @fecha_mov, @fecha_cierre, @egreso
   While @@fetch_status = 0 Begin 

    If  @cont = 0 Begin     
      Set @uf_mov       =  (select dbo.FNC_BENFON_TraeValorUF(@fecha_mov))
      Set @uf_general   =  (Select uf_general from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@iPersona and id=(select max(id) from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@iPersona ) )
      Set @capital_ant      =  (Select capital    from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@iPersona and id=(select max(id) from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@iPersona ) )
      Set @capital      =  Round(@uf_general * @uf_mov,0)
      Set @reajuste     =  @capital - @capital_ant
      Insert into gacpro_reajuste (iPersona,uf_general,uf_movimiento,capital,reajuste,egreso,fecha_movimiento,cierre) 
          values(@ipersona, @uf_general, @uf_mov, @capital, @reajuste, @egreso, @fecha_mov,'Ene retiro')
    End

    If @cont > 0 Begin  
      Set @uf_mov       =  (select dbo.FNC_BENFON_TraeValorUF(@fecha_mov))
          Set @egreso       =  (Select egreso from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@iPersona and id=(select max(id) from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@iPersona ) and cierre = 'Ene retiro'  ) 
      Set @egreso_uf    =  @egreso / @uf_mov
          Set @uf_general_ant   =  (Select uf_general from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@iPersona and id=(select max(id) from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@iPersona ) and cierre = 'Ene retiro' )
      Set @uf_general   =  @uf_general_ant - @egreso_uf
          Set @capital_ant      =  (Select capital    from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@iPersona and id=(select max(id) from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@iPersona ) and cierre = 'Ene retiro')
      Set @capital_resta    =  @uf_general * (Select uf_movimiento from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@iPersona and id=(select max(id) from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@iPersona ) and cierre = 'Ene retiro' )
      Set @capital      =  Round(@uf_general * @uf_mov,0)
      Set @reajuste     =  @capital - @capital_resta

      Insert into gacpro_reajuste (iPersona,uf_general,uf_movimiento,capital,reajuste,egreso,fecha_movimiento,cierre) 
          values(@ipersona, @uf_general, @uf_mov, @capital, @reajuste, @egreso, @fecha_mov,'Ene retiro')
    End

    Fetch Next From cRetiros Into @tipo_mov, @fecha_mov, @fecha_cierre, @egreso
    Set @cont = @cont + 1
   End 
Close cRetiros
Deallocate cRetiros
```

Comment: Hola Sam, me parece que tu pregunta deja lugar a muchas dudas, por ejemplo, ¿el `INSERT` o el `UPDATE` son en la misma tabla o en otra? ¿el nuevo registro a qué se refiere exactamente, a realizar un `INSERT` en la misma tabla? Entre más detalle otorgues será más fácil darte una respuesta puntual al problema presentado

Comment: Si se deben trabajar todos los registros, uno por uno, creo que el uso de un cursor es inevitable. ¿Con el cursor también se tarda diez horas o solo con el while? Lo que se podría optimizar es el proceso que se ejecuta para cada registro. También hay procesos pesados, por ejemplo, un cierre contable, que es inevitable que sean tardados y se corren por las noches, o en horas que no sean de producción.

Comment: Quizá lo mejor sea reformular la pregunta, para verificar la optimización del procesamiento que se le da a cada registro.

Comment: Hola amigos, gracias por responder. Agregué parte de mi código, para que se entienda la idea. Recorro cada movimiento, le paso el valor a una variable y con ellas hago los cálculos, los cuales finalmente los inserto a una nueva tabla llamda GACPRO_reajuste

Comment: Veo que tu código parte de una tabla temporal. ¿Estás seguro que la construcción de aquella tabla no forma parte también de tu problema de rendimiento?

Comment: Si modificas el cursor para que solo ejecute un registro, ¿cuánto se tarda?. Además, hay que verificar el query plan de instrucciones como esta: Set @uf_general   =  (Select uf_general from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@iPersona and id=(select max(id) from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@iPersona ) ). ¿Estas consultas utiliza los índices? Podrías eliminar los insert y dejar el cursor con una instrucción e ir analizando cuál es la que se está tardando.

Comment: @jYass, al modificar el cursor para un solo registro, este tarda no mas de 2 segundos.

Comment: Veo que también repites `select max(id) from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@iPersona` varias veces. Obviamente puedes tratar de evitar aquella repetición. Pero aun así, me cuesta entender la lógica de esa sentencia. ¿Cual es la idea tras conseguir el `max(id)`? Me parece muy costosa esa operación... estoy seguro que hay una mejor alternativa, pero primero hay que entender lo que estás tratando de hacer.

Comment: sstam, el máximo lo hago porque necesito ir colgándome del movimiento anterior para reajustarlo con el nuevo.

Comment: 2 segundos ya es tardado, los 120,000 registros por dos segundos cada uno son 240,000 segundos, cuando un día tiene 86,400 segundos. Revisar el query plan de cada una de las consultas que alimenta a las variables con set.

Comment: Se repite mucho las mismas consultas, y solo es necesaria una vez, por ejemplo en el primer bloque: select @ capital_ant = capital, @ uf_general = uf_general from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@ iPersona and id=(select max(id) from gacpro_reajuste where iPersona=@ iPersona ) ) ..., asi se ejecuta una sola vez.

Comment: El procedimiento tiene varios detallitos que se pueden mejorar.  Pero la verdadera solución es de reescribir el procedimiento para combinar toda la lógica en unos cuantas sentencias insert, o tal vez solo una. De lo que puedo ver, me parece posible. Pero para poder sugerirte esta forma ideal de escribir el procedimiento, tendrías que tomar el tiempo de describir bien las tablas envueltas y la lógica de tu procedimiento. Toma en cuenta que no tenemos todos los detalles y contexto que tu tienes.

Comment: Bueno amigos, voy a darle una vuelta al procedimiento en base a sus consejos y sugerencias y les comento como va.  Gracias por la paciencia y disposición